# problems with http post json (spring/angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, http, spring-mvc

[i create an spring/angularjs application but i have some problems with "post",when i tried to test the controller without angularjs i had this message :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wa0Y.jpg)

"timestamp": 1495521855274,
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
"message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryShaAnQBDa47tg35j' not supported",
"path": "/employe1"

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C94KL.jpg)

```
@Autowired
private EmployeMetier EmployeMetier;
@RequestMapping(value="/employe1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Employe saveEmploye(@RequestBody Employe e) {

    return EmployeMetier.saveEmploye(e);
}
```

[this my angularjs app][3]

```
$scope.ajouter_employe=function(){
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/employe1",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: {idEmploye: $scope.idEmploye}
}).then( function(response){
               alert('yes');
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your @RequestMapping as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employe1",method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```